# ASP.NET default authorization database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, authorization

In default authorization database that is created by wizard, there are two tables for one entity. For example:

aspnet_users and users, aspnet_roles and roles, etc.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you check the create date of the tables to see if they were really created at the same time?

Comment: Why you downvote if you explain, You can help me for qualty question.

Comment: not same time. aspnet_roles created to Roles two hours before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. aspnet_ prefixed tables created by aspnet_regsql and others (Roles, Profiles, Users, etc) created by web site administration tool when added the user and role. Thank your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Something has gone wrong? The default database created by aspnet_regsql for authentication has three tables; aspnet_users, aspnet_roles and aspnet_applications. Adding roles for authorization adds a few more, but they're still all aspnet_ prefixed.

You can check this for yourself by running

```
aspnet_regsql -sqlexportonly
```

and examining the SQL it produces. There's not even a way to remove the prefix when you register SQL for application services.

Comment: I deleted all aspnet_prefixed tables. But project is working well with the other tables. Why is this happening?